# install php-gd ext on Debian

Tags: debian, php-7.2, php-gd

I'm not able to install php-gd extension on my server.

I have php 7.2:

```
PHP 7.2.10-1+0~20181001133426.7+jessie~1.gbpb6e829 (cli) (built: Oct  1 2018 13:50:53) ( NTS )
```

and debian 8 linux:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 8
```

command to install GD extension:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd
```

and result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libc-ares2 libnfsidmap2 libpcre16-3 libpcre32-3 libuuid-perl libv8-3.14.5 php-http-request php-mail-mimedecode php-net-dime php-net-url
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php7.2-gd
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 27.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 186 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main php7.2-gd amd64 7.2.10-1+0~20181001133426.7+jessie~1.gbpb6e829 [27.5 kB]
Err https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie/main php7.2-gd amd64 7.2.10-1+0~20181001133426.7+jessie~1.gbpb6e829
  HttpError404
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-gd_7.2.10-1+0~20181001133426.7+jessie~1.gbpb6e829_amd64.deb  HttpError404

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

any ideas how to fix it please?

Answer (score 9):

The `php-7.2-gd` package isn't available in Debian repositories (yet). But that doesn't matter, of course you can install it anyway. There's a great website named [DEB.SURY.ORG](https://deb.sury.org/) that packages different software into Debian and Ubuntu (especially PHP packages).

First, download the key to the package source:

```
$ sudo curl -s https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then create a `.list` file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`:

```
$ echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ buster main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
```

Then `update` and `upgrade` your distro:

```
$ sudo apt update -y && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
```

Now you should be able to install the `php7.2-gd` package by running:

```
$ sudo apt install php7.2-gd
```

Comment: More portable execution: ```curl -s https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg | sudo apt-key add -```

Comment: Doesn't work with buster: ```Package php7.2-gd is not available, but is referred to by another package.```

Comment: @viktorkho Sorry, you're right. I have updated my answer. **NOTE**: At that time `buster` was the codename for `debian-testing`, and that was the issue. Now, `buster` has become `debian-stable` and so, the above answer should provide an option how to get the `php7.2-gd` package installed. Tested on Debian Buster (stable), works.

Answer (score -1):

Run the following commands:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt install php7.2-gd
```

The error "Failed to fetch" because `apt` will try to use an outaded database to download/install an old (removed) version of `php7.2-gd` from `sury` repository.

In [08-Mar-2019](https://packages.sury.org/php/pool/main/p/php7.2/) the `php7.2-gd_7.2.10-1+0~20181001133426.7+jessie~1.gbpb6e829_amd64.deb` is updated to a new version `php7.2-gd_7.2.16-1+0~20190307202206.17+jessie~1.gbpa7be82_amd64.deb`, the old version is removed, that's why `apt` fail to retrieve the information about the old package.

The  Ondřej Surý  repository is already configured correctly, `apt` doesn't show any error.