# Debian - existence official PHP package

Tags: php, package, debian, debian-stretch

I have a question about *PHP* packages on *Debian*. My project currently is in *PHP* 7.4 but this version is no longer supported since 28 Nov 2022.

The problem is, I need to pass to *PHP* 8.0 (minimum) or 8.1 (last version available).

Does it exist an official *PHP* package for *Debian* 10 or *Debian* 11 (or stretch version) ? It is necessary for security constraints.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [install php-gd ext on Debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55318499/install-php-gd-ext-on-debian)

Comment: related [Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.0' in debian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66158446/9193372)

Comment: Note: Supported Debian distribution handle security fixes, so you should have anyway security updates. You can also use testing distribution of Debian (which delivers 8.2), it is pretty stable because it is preparing for release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP version in Debian 10 is 7.3 and in 11 its 7.4 https://wiki.debian.org/PHP#Available_versions
If you need PHP 8.0 or newer you could use a repo like https://packages.sury.org/php/